# Set classname for datepicker to use as component in Redux Form field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I am trying to set a className to the `DatePicker` component in redux form material ui like.

My custom component is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { DatePicker } from 'redux-form-material-ui'

const CustomDatePicker = props => (
  <DatePicker 
    {...props}
  />
)

export default CustomDatePicker;
```

And I am trying to use it like below:

```
var datePicker = <CustomDatePicker className="testClass" />;
...
...
<Field name="dateTime" type="text" component={datePicker} format={value => value ? new Date(value) : null}  />
```

but I am getting an error saying `Invalid Prop component supplied to Field`

Can someone point to me what do I need to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338367/react-datepicker-with-redux-form/46399129#46399129 have a look on this

Answer (score 0):

Redux-form `Field` passes own props to component that will be rendered, so you can pass `className` to `Field`, see example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { DatePicker } from 'redux-form-material-ui';

import './style.css';

const ExampleForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>Date</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            className="testClass"
            name="date"
            component={DatePicker}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'example',
})(ExampleForm);
```

`className='testClass'` will be passed to `DatePicker` component in the example.

[image: Edit Redux Form - Simple Example]