# react-datepicker Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-datepicker

I am using react-datepicker with redux-form as described in  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422269/datepicker-in-redux-form) but when I change the datetime format from "LLL" to "mm:HH YYYY:MM:DD" I keep getting this error

> Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.

and the datepicker is freezing.
Here is my code

```
renderDatePicker = ({input, label, meta: {touched, error} }) => {
    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label>{label}</label>
            <DatePicker className="form-control" {...input}
                        dateFormat="mm:HH YYYY:MM:DD"
                        showTimeSelect
                        timeIntervals={15}
                        selected={input.value ? moment(input.value): null} />
            {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
        </div>
    );
}

<Field name="date" component={this.renderDatePicker} label="تاريخ الانتهاء"/>
```

Comment: In my case this was due to 0000-00-00 for 'selected'